# Connotations of the word “cohort”

Tags: nouns, connotation

Outside of the scientific sense (*cohort study*), does the word *cohort* have positive, negative or neutral connotations?  The dictionary defines it as a group of people or single companion and it originated as the name of a division of men in a Roman legion.  However, I feel that nowadays it is usually used to describe a group of people who are up to no good.

Comment: Looking at COCA, I can't see very many -- if any -- negative connotations. The vast majority are of the *cohort study* sense or similar, even outside academic publications. It simply means a particular group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the following [extract](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cohort), the term is used mainly with a neutral connotation:

> - A cohort is a group of people who are around the same age, like a cohort of college students who have similar experiences and concerns.
> - The word cohort was originally used to describe a military unit in ancient Rome. You can see how this retains traces of the word’s origins: cohorts are bound together by similar circumstances just like a group of soldiers in a military unit. ***Some language purists insist that the word only describe a group, such as a cohort of accountants, but it can also refer to companions or supporters, such as “Susie and her cohorts.”***

(Vocabulary.com)

The [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cohort) suggests a usage with a disapproving (possibly negative) connotation:

> - ***(specialist) a group of people who share a common feature or aspect of behaviour***
>
>   - *the 1999 birth cohort (= all those born in 1999)*
> - ***(disapproving) a member of a group of people who support another person***
>
>   - *Robinson and his cohorts were soon ejected from the hall*.
>   - *The director made his entrance followed by his cohort of technicians and production assistants.*